# Functional way in python to change this list into another

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, functional-programming

I have a list `[2,3,0,3]`
And want to generate a list

```
[1,0,1,2]
```

The reasoning is that 1 zero appears, no one appears, 1 two appears and 2 threes appear in the input list.

Is there a non `for` loopy procedural way to do this in python?

Comment: Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: It is similar to *grouping* operation in database.

Comment: Thanks Nishant, the guy ubnutu shows Counter, so very close, but i updated my question to have a missing 1

Comment: Your output list should be from `min - max` or `0-max`. Suppose the list is `[5,9,7]` what should be the output?

Comment: That would be something like `[my_counter[i] for i in range(max(my_counter))]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which finds count of elements:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [2,3,0,3]

c = Counter(lst)
print([c[x] for x in range(max(lst)+1)])
# [1, 0, 1, 2]
```

An alternate way avoiding loops:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [2,3,0,3]

c = dict.fromkeys(range(max(lst)+1), 0)
c.update(Counter(lst))

print(c.values())
# # [1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use the following code:

```
lst = [2,3,0,1,3]
#Get list unique values using set
set_lst = sorted(set(lst))
#For each unique element, use the count method
counts = [lst.count(i) for i in set_lst]
```

At first, we find out all the unique elements of the list, by using a `set` object, which stores unique elements only. Then we traverse through the list and use the `count` method to get the counts of each element, which are sorted in order.

Comment: I think this is a more built-in method. Obviously, using a `Counter` or `itertools` could be faster

Comment: Have an upvote but more importantly look at Austins answer, more elegant

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `count`:

```
l = [2, 3, 0, 3]

assert len(l) == max(l) + 1

[l.count(num) for num, _ in enumerate(l)]
# [1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: always fun to see other ideas, but because of the need for the assertion, i still favor Counter  way, have an upvote

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid `for` keyword at any price, then you might use `map` instead, following way:

```
a = [2,3,0,3]
out = list(map(lambda x:a.count(x), list(range(max(a)+1))))
print(out) #[1, 0, 1, 2]
```

This solution assumes that `a` contains solely non-negative integers and is not empty `list`.